# Why does `x =! 5` return false?

Tags: ruby, boolean, operator-precedence

I've been studying operator precedence and it was explained to me that `x =! 5` returns `false`. I can't seem to explain why to myself again. I know `=!` isn't a operator so then `x` and `5` remain. So does that mean Ruby doesn't know what to do? If so ruby should return an error because `x` can have no value? Does Ruby stop at the operator and then assign a value of `false` to `x`?

```
x =! 5 
=> false
```

Comment: Whereas `x != 5` (`!=` operator testing for inequality) would of course generate an error if x wasn't defined, or `true` if x was nil (or anything other than 5).

Comment: In addition to precedence, BasicObject is the parent class of all classes in Ruby - this is where you will find `!` defined. All  objects, when present in a condition, are either truthy or falsy. Ruby's flexibility allows for many variations `!(5)`, `! 5`, `5.!` or `!5` or even `!'hello'` will all evaluate to false.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is because `x =! 5` is being interpreted as `x = (!5)` ([`!` has higer precedence than `=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)). In Ruby every object is `true` except `nil` and `false`. `5` has *truthy* value which you are negating using the operator `!`. So `false` as result is being assigned to the local variable `x`.

[`!` *Called Logical `NOT` Operator*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) - is used to reverse the logical state of its operand. If a condition is `true`, then Logical `NOT` operator will make `false`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a thing as `=!` operator in Ruby. `!=` is what checks for `not equal`.

So basically, when the parser is looking at the code and find an `=`, it looks for other operators that start with `=` such as `==`. If it finds no match, which is the case here ( `=!` ), it considers the expression as an assignment, and assigns the right hand side to the left hand side. In this case, the right hand side of the `=` is `! 5`, which is equal to false.